# Selectbox updating when second selextbox has sth. selected

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, many-to-many

I want to have a dropdown-select box which lists all group-names out of my database and when I select a group a second select-box should list all the users which are in this selected group. Perfect would be if the site doesn't have to reload. But I dont know how to do this.

These are my tables:

```
+----------+      +--------------+     
| users    |      | users_groups |     +--------------+
+----------+      +--------------+     | groups       |
| user_id  |----->| user_id      |     +--------------+
| username |      | group_id     |<----| group_id     |
| realname |      +--------------+     | group_name   |
| password |                           | group_desc   |
+----------+                           +--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ajax to display and updated second select box, based on first selection or choice. More details for ajax please go through

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/